# Caching Maven with Docker and Kotlin

Tags: maven, docker, kotlin, dockerfile

I am trying to warm up my Docker + Maven cache before building a Kotlin project.
As suggested by many Maven/Docker threads, my docker file looks like this:

```
COPY pom.xml .
RUN  mvn dependency:go-offline
COPY ./src/ src/
RUN  mvn package
```

The thought is that if I change a file in the ./src directory, I want docker cache to skip maven's lengthy dependency download page.

My problem is that the `mvn package` command still downloads alot of files.
I tried to use `mvn -o package` (maven offline flag) to diagnose what dependencies are missing, but it just complains that it cannot download dependencies. But I would have expected that the dependencies would allready be downloaded in the previous step. Here are the errors that I get with the "-o" flag:

```
Step 8/13 : RUN  mvn dependency:go-offline
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 0334facb9cc9
Step 9/13 : COPY ./src/ src/
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 27149a191017
Step 10/13 : RUN  mvn -o package
 ---> Running in 5183eced32ca
Warning: JAVA_HOME environment variable is not set.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building auth 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ auth ---
[WARNING] The POM for org.apache.maven:maven-core:jar:2.0.6 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for org.apache.maven:maven-monitor:jar:2.0.6 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:2.0.5 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for org.apache.maven.shared:maven-filtering:jar:1.1 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interpolation:jar:1.13 is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.882 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-07-12T07:02:23+00:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 13M/174M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) on project auth: Execution default-resources of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources failed: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-project:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-profile:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-artifact-manager:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-repository-metadata:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-registry:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-core:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-settings:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-model:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-monitor:jar:2.0.6, classworlds:classworlds:jar:1.1-alpha-2, org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:2.0.5, org.apache.maven.shared:maven-filtering:jar:1.1, org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interpolation:jar:1.13: Cannot access central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) in offline mode and the artifact org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.0.6 has not been downloaded from it before. -> [Help 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following mvn commands, it saved me from the maven error.

```
RUN  mvn --batch-mode --errors --strict-checksums --threads 1C \
     org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:3.0.2:go-offline

RUN  mvn --batch-mode --errors --offline package
```

Comment: Please expain the purpose of each flag.

Comment: I played around with your solution. It seems like -B is the only flag that matters. Reading the CLI docs,  I have no idea why it works, but it does :-).

Comment: Refer [doc](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.1.0/maven-embedder/cli.html) to know about meaning of every CLI option.

Comment: @sarang With regards to my previous comment: the doc does not explain why -B would matter with regards to "offline". (I allready read it before posting my comment :-) )

Comment: It would help to add more detail to this answer

Answer (score 0):

From what I gathered from various sources `go-offline` not always handles caching packages in a correct way, leaving some of them outside of the local repository (see pull request on [GitHub](https://github.com/apache/maven-dependency-plugin/pull/130)).

In my case, the standard `mvn dependency:go-offline` used `go-offline` 2.8 and returned errors. I then tried running `mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:3.2.0:go-offline` but I still had some issues with different packages.

What worked for me was using a different "go-offline" plugin available at [GitHub](https://github.com/qaware/go-offline-maven-plugin).

Using

```
mvn de.qaware.maven:go-offline-maven-plugin:resolve-dependencies
```

finally did the job.